# Find Vector Equation for Plane in which two intersecting lines lie

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The two lines $$[x,y,z] = [1,1,1] + t[4,4,-8]$$ and $$[x,y,z] = [1,1,1] + s[4,-4,0]$$ intersect at **one** point. Using this point of intersection as the *initial* point, find the vector equation of the unique plane in which both lines lie.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the intersection point?

Comment: The intersection is at [1,1,1], so I figured that I could just add the vector that is multiplied by a scalar from one equation to the other and that would be the vector equation of the plane for intersecting lines but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's it. Very good!

Comment: @amsmath Oh look at that! Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: Never mind. Go on this way.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what your last comment means @amsmath

Comment: It means that I appreciate your thanks and that you are free to be more self-confident concerning your math skills.